# Как не вернуться обратно на заставку?

Tags: java, android

Хочу сделать так, чтобы при запуске приложения появлялась заставка, и через несколько секунд заставка пропадала и появлялось главное меню.

Вот как я все придумал реализовать: При запуске приложения запускаем `AsyncTask`, и в нем я ставлю таймер на пять секунд, после того как они истекли, переходит на главную *Activity*, и во время этих пяти секунд висит заставка.

Как сделать так, чтобы пользователь не мог снова вернутся на заставку при нажатии кнопки *BACK*?

Comment: закройте заставку с `finish()` при переходе в `Activity`

Comment: @SaidolimDjuraev Понял. спасибо. попробую - отпишу

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Реализация](http://www.andreamaglie.com/android-simple-splash-screen/) с корректной обработкой нажатия кнопки <kbd>Назад</kbd> :

**SplashActivity:**

```
public class SplashActivity extends Activity {

    private static int SPLASH_TIME_OUT = 2000; // 2 seconds

    private Handler mHandler;

    private Runnable mRunnable = new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            startMainActivity();
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);

        mHandler = new Handler();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        mHandler.postDelayed(mRunnable, SPLASH_TIME_OUT);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();

        removeCallbacks();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();

        removeCallbacks();
    }

    private void removeCallbacks() {
        if (mHandler != null) {
            mHandler.removeCallbacks(mRunnable);
        }
    }

    private void startMainActivity() {
        startActivity(new Intent(this, MainActivity.class));

        finish();
    }
}
```

**AndroidManifest.xml:**

```
<activity
        android:name=".SplashActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
        android:label="@string/application_name"
        android:noHistory="true" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Comment: В том чтобы и `finish()` вызывать и флаг `noHistory` добавить есть какой-то скрытый смысл, или на всякий случай?

Comment: @anber Я не автор этого кода и с полной ответственностью не могу ответить на этот вопрос. У Андреа в блоге есть обратная связь и комментарии - можете спросить у нее, какой она вложила смысл :). Я думаю, что `noHistory` указан с конкретной целью исключить из стека возвратов, а `finish()` по логике выполнения - закрыть сплэшскрин, о дублировании некоторых действий не всегда думаешь.

Answer (score 3):

Чтобы не возвращаться на активити по нажатию на кнопку back, вариантов несколько:

1. В манифесте у активити добавить флаг `android:noHistory="true"`
2. Вызывать `finish()` у активити на которую вы больше не хотите возвращаться.

Answer (score 2):

есть такая штука/концепция
 splash Activity - вот про неё:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/5486970/5292979

определяем layout

```
      <ImageView android:id="@+id/splashscreen" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:src="@drawable/splash"
              android:layout_gravity="center"/>

      <TextView android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Hello World, splash"/>
```

и создаём Activity

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;

public class Splash extends Activity {

   /** Duration of wait **/
   private final int SPLASH_DISPLAY_LENGTH = 1000;

   /** Called when the activity is first created. */
   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
       super.onCreate(icicle);
       setContentView(R.layout.splashscreen);

       /* New Handler to start the Menu-Activity 
        * and close this Splash-Screen after some seconds.*/
       new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable(){
           @Override
           public void run() {
               /* Create an Intent that will start the Menu-Activity. */
               Intent mainIntent = new Intent(Splash.this,YourActivity.class);
               Splash.this.startActivity(mainIntent);
               Splash.this.finish();
           }
       }, SPLASH_DISPLAY_LENGTH);
   }
   @Override
   public void onBackPressed() {
   }
}
```

Comment: Хотя по ссылке можно найти ответ на вопрос, лучше указать здесь самое главное, а ссылку приводить в качестве источника. Если страница, на которую ведет ссылка, будет изменена, ответ-ссылка может стать недействительным.

Comment: хорошо, спасибо, исправлю)

Comment: Если нажать `back` во время того как сплеш отображается то он исчезнет и выйдет на рабочий стол, а через секунду появится следующая активити, не так ли?

Comment: а кто мешает это обработать?

Comment: спс за подсказку

Answer (score 1):

Лучше для реализации заставки использовать fragment

Comment: Чем fragment лучше?

Comment: Пример скажем у тебя отрабатывает Asynctask после того как он закончил свою работу он возвращает какие то данные эти данные придется отправить на основной Активити используя intent. Возникают  ситуацию когда возращаемый объект это массив объектов ArrayList<Object> в данном случае возвращать через intent будет сложновато

Answer (score 0):

Также можно посмотреть здесь, как это делается в Android Studio пошагово:

[Ссылка](http://www.coderefer.com/android-splash-screen-example-tutorial/)

Шаг 1: Создаем новый layout с названием splash.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:background="@drawable/splash_image"
 android:orientation="vertical">

</LinearLayout>
```

Шаг 2: Создаем Activity с названием SplashScreen

```
public class SplashScreen extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.splash);

        Thread timerThread = new Thread(){
            public void run(){
                try{
                    sleep(3000);
                }catch(InterruptedException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }finally{
                    Intent intent = new Intent(SplashScreen.this,MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            }
        };
        timerThread.start();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPause();
        finish();
    }

}
```

Шаг 3: Открываем AndroidManifest.xml и добавляем intent-filter

```
 <activity
   android:name=".SplashScreen"
   android:label="@string/app_name" >
   <intent-filter>
     <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />     
     <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
   </intent-filter>
 </activity>
```

P.S: Время жизни SplashScreen всегда можно настроить, изменив значение в методе sleep() на необходимое (в примере оно составляет 3 сек. == 3000 мс).

Также можно изменить переход из SplashScreen не в MainActivity (как в примере), а в любую другую Activity, указав название необходимой Activity в блоке finally, `new Intent(SplashScreen.this,SecondActivity.class)`.

Comment: одна только строчка - sleep(3000); в том примере повергает в ужас :)

Comment: Хотя по ссылке можно найти ответ на вопрос, лучше указать здесь самое главное, а ссылку приводить в качестве источника. Если страница, на которую ведет ссылка, будет изменена, ответ-ссылка может стать недействительным.

Comment: @s_klepcha чем плох sleep(3000) ?

Comment: чисто субъективное мнение, но по мне топорным стилем попахивает, отложенное выполнение можно сделать изящнее, например через Handler